# What is the exact length of a point (pt) in Lotus Forms?

Tags: typography, lotus

i am going to convert couple Lotus Forms forms to web pages. So i checked what it uses for font size. It is pt, which make me think that it is point. I tried same values for font sizes, like Arial,Bold,7pt. BUT,
text in webpage is smaller than text in Lotus Forms. and it is easy to chatch, not a difference that requires magnifier.

Which leads to that, Lotus Forms and browsers use different kind of point(s). I have searched and found that there might be different point(s).
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/metric-typo/
So what is Lotus Forms's point and what is browser's point?

Comment: I can't actually answer your question, but you might check Lotus's support forum for Forms: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lformsforum.nsf

Answer (score 0):

Just check the resulting HTML- Code (View - Source) in the browser. And you will find, that the "Points" in Lotus Notes are converted to "font"- Tags with size=1 (8 Point), size=2 (9 Point) ...

In Addition Using "Default Font" in lotus Notes results in a unpredictable result in the browser (Depending on the default Fonts of the OS the Browser runs or of the Browser).

if you really want to have Text looking identical in Lotus Notes and the Browser, then you have to use CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) to define Font- Size, Font- Family, etc. 
You can do this directly in every Block- Element by editiing the Style- Properties (The @ Tab in the properties, unfortunately not available for text that is not contained in a table or another Element), or by inserting a CSS- Resource in the Form.

better get Familiar with CSS if you aren't already.